# Add advanced search data

Tags: javascript, php, html, search

can not search using two different fields, name and gender, can you add an advanced search with more imput?
Place the files and codes to help you better understand where to add advanced search imput

getdata.php

```js
<?php

if(isset($_GET['page'])){
    //Include pagination class file
    include('Pagination.php');
    
    //Include database configuration file
    include('dbConfig.php');
    
    $start = !empty($_GET['page'])?$_GET['page']:0;
    $limit = 25;
     //set conditions for search
    $whereSQL = $orderSQL = '';
    $keywords = $_GET['keywords'];
    $keyname = $_GET['keyname'];
    $sortBy = $_GET['sortBy'];

    if(!empty($keyname)){
        $whereSQL = "WHERE name LIKE '%".$keyname."%'";
    }
     if(!empty($keywords)){
        $whereSQ = "WHERE member_group_id LIKE '".$keywords."'";
    }

    if(!empty($sortBy)){
        $orderSQL = " ORDER BY name ".$sortBy;
    }else{
        $orderSQL = " ORDER BY name DESC ";
    }

    //get number of rows
    $queryNum = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as name FROM ILFREE_core_members ".$whereSQL.$whereSQ.$orderSQL);
    $resultNum = $queryNum->fetch_assoc();
    $rowCount = $resultNum['name'];

    //initialize pagination class
    $pagConfig = array(
        'currentPage' => $start,
        'totalRows' => $rowCount,
        'perPage' => $limit,
        'link_func' => 'searchFilter'
    );
    $pagination =  new Pagination($pagConfig);
    
    //get rows
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM ILFREE_core_members $whereSQL $whereSQ $orderSQL LIMIT $start,$limit");

    if($query->num_rows > 0){ ?>
        <div class="GETs_list">
        <?php
while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
$GroupID = $row["member_group_id"];
$IDgroup = array('29','77','62','83','46','43','73','58','68','2','78','63','82','45','42','71','52','67','27','76','60','81','44','41','70','56','65');
$GETID = $row['member_id'];
$Name = $row["name"];
$photo = $row["pp_main_photo"];
$bannato = '7';


?>
<div class="list_item">
<?php
// name

echo '<a href="http://www.ilfree.it/index.php?/profile/' . $GETID . '-' . $Name . '"  title="Visualizza il profilo di ' . $Name . '" ><h2>' . $Name . '</h2></a>';

// foto
if(empty($photo)) { if(in_array($GroupID, $IDgroup)) {
echo '<a href="http://www.ilfree.it/index.php?/profile/' . $GETID . '-' . $Name . '" title="Visualizza il profilo di ' . $Name . '"><img src="http://www.ilfree.it/uploads/file/search_femmina.png"/></a>'; }
elseif ($bannato == $GroupID) {
echo '<a href="http://www.ilfree.it/index.php?/profile/' . $GETID . '-' . $Name . '" title="Visualizza il profilo di ' . $Name . '"><img src="http://www.ilfree.it/uploads/file/ban.png"/></a>'; }
else {
echo '<a href="http://www.ilfree.it/index.php?/profile/' . $GETID . '-' . $Name . '" title="Visualizza il profilo di ' . $Name . '"><img src="http://www.ilfree.it/uploads/file/search_maschio.png"/></a>'; } }
else{
echo '<a href="http://www.ilfree.it/index.php?/profile/' . $GETID . '-' . $Name . '" title="Visualizza il profilo di ' . $Name . '"><img src="http://www.ilfree.it/uploads/profile_photos/' . $photo . '"/></a>';
}








?>






    
          


            

            
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <?php echo $pagination->createLinks(); ?>
<?php } } ?>
```

index.php

```js
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>


</head>
<body>




<div class="GET-search-panel">
    <input type="text" id="keyname" placeholder="name" onkeyup="searchFilter()"/>

    <input type="text" id="keywords" placeholder="Type keywords to filter GETs" onkeyup="searchFilter()"/>
    <select id="sortBy" onchange="searchFilter()">
        <option value="">Sort By</option>
        <option value="asc">Ascending</option>
        <option value="desc">Descending</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="GET-wrapper">
    <div id="GETs_content">
    <?php
    //Include pagination class file
    include('Pagination.php');
   
    //Include database configuration file
    include('dbConfig.php');
   
    $limit = 25;

    //get number of rows
    $queryNum = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as ilfreexxx FROM ILFREE_core_members");
    $resultNum = $queryNum->fetch_assoc();
    $rowCount = $resultNum['ilfreexxx'];
   
    //initialize pagination class
    $pagConfig = array(
        'totalRows' => $rowCount,
        'perPage' => $limit,
        'link_func' => 'searchFilter'
    );
    $pagination =  new Pagination($pagConfig);
   
    //get rows
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM ILFREE_core_members ORDER BY member_id DESC LIMIT $limit");
   
    if($query->num_rows > 0){ ?>
        <div class="GETs_list">

            
<?php         

while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
$GroupID = $row["member_group_id"];
$IDgroup = array('29','77','62','83','46','43','73','58','68','2','78','63','82','45','42','71','52','67','27','76','60','81','44','41','70','56','65');
$GETID = $row['member_id'];
$Name = $row["name"];
$photo = $row["pp_main_photo"];
$bannato = '7';


?>
<div class="list_item">
<?php
// name

echo '<a href="http://www.ilfree.it/index.php?/profile/' . $GETID . '-' . $Name . '"  title="Visualizza il profilo di ' . $Name . '" ><h2>' . $Name . '</h2></a>';

// foto
if(empty($photo)) { if(in_array($GroupID, $IDgroup)) {
echo '<a href="http://www.ilfree.it/index.php?/profile/' . $GETID . '-' . $Name . '" title="Visualizza il profilo di ' . $Name . '"><img src="http://www.ilfree.it/uploads/file/search_femmina.png"/></a>'; }
elseif ($bannato == $GroupID) {
echo '<a href="http://www.ilfree.it/index.php?/profile/' . $GETID . '-' . $Name . '" title="Visualizza il profilo di ' . $Name . '"><img src="http://www.ilfree.it/uploads/file/ban.png"/></a>'; }
else {
echo '<a href="http://www.ilfree.it/index.php?/profile/' . $GETID . '-' . $Name . '" title="Visualizza il profilo di ' . $Name . '"><img src="http://www.ilfree.it/uploads/file/search_maschio.png"/></a>'; } }
else{
echo '<a href="http://www.ilfree.it/index.php?/profile/' . $GETID . '-' . $Name . '" title="Visualizza il profilo di ' . $Name . '"><img src="http://www.ilfree.it/uploads/profile_photos/' . $photo . '"/></a>';
}








?>






   
          


            

            
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
        </div>   </div>
        <?php echo $pagination->createLinks(); ?>
    <?php } ?>

</div>

<style>

body {
    background: #e7e7e7 url(http://carpanelli-art.com/wp-content/themes/pacifico/images/bgs/bg_i_4.jpg) repeat;
    font-family: "FS Albert Light", "Myriad Pro", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.GET-wrapper {
    padding: 10px;
    background: #fdfdfd;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
.list_item {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    border: 4px solid #f1f1f1;
    margin: 4px;
}
.list_item:hover {
       border: 4px solid #d6e9ff;

}
.list_item a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #b1b1b1;
   font-size: 10px;
    text-align: center;

}
.list_item a:hover {
       color: #8a8a8a;
}
.list_item img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 220px;
    display: list-item;
}

.list_item h2 {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    background: #f4f5f9;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
    color: #3f4752;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #fff;
}
 #GETs_content {
    width: 70%;
        margin: 0 auto;
}
.GETs_list {display: inline-block;}
 div.pagination {
    font-family: "Lucida Sans", Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    padding:20px;
    margin:7px;
    display: inline-block;
}
div.pagination a {
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 0.5em 0.64em 0.43em 0.64em;
    background-color: #ee4e4e;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}
div.pagination a:hover, div.pagination a:active {
    padding: 0.5em 0.64em 0.43em 0.64em;
    margin: 2px;
    background-color: #de1818;
    color: #fff;
}
div.pagination span.current {
    padding: 0.5em 0.64em 0.43em 0.64em;
    margin: 2px;
    background-color: #f6efcc;
    color: #6d643c;
}
div.pagination span.disabled {
    display:none;
}
</style>
            <!-- JavaScript -->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
function searchFilter(page_num) {
    page_num = page_num?page_num:0;
    var keywords = $('#keywords').val();
    var keyname = $('#keyname').val();
    var sortBy = $('#sortBy').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'getData.php',
        data:'page='+page_num+'&keyname='+keyname+'&keywords='+keywords+'&sortBy='+sortBy,
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('.loading-overlay').show();
        },
        success: function (html) {
            $('#GETs_content').html(html);
            $('.loading-overlay').fadeOut("slow");
        }
    });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I look anxiously for your help

Comment: test:http://www.ilfree.it/test/

Answer (score 0):

You could build an array with all the conditional clauses, and then format that array into an appropriate SQL where clause.  It needs to be mentioned however that you are not escaping your input to SQL and are susceptible to SQL Injection attacks.  Here's some sample code for a very simple query builder.

```
$start = !empty($_GET['page'])?$_GET['page']:0;
$limit = 25;

# Build array of orderings
$orderQueries = [];
if (isset($_GET['sortBy']) && !empty($_GET['sortBy'])) {
    $sortBy = $_GET['sortBy'];
    $orderQueries[] = "name $sortBy";
} else {
    $orderQueries[] = "name DESC";
}

# Build array of conditionals
$whereQueries = [];
if (isset($_GET['name']) && !empty($_GET['name'])) {
    $name = $_GET['name'];
    $whereQueries[] = "name LIKE '%$name%'";
}
if (isset($_GET['age']) && !empty($_GET['age'])) {
    $age = $_GET['age'];
    $whereQueries[] = "age = $age";
}
if (isset($_GET['keywords']) && !empty($_GET['keywords'])) {
    $keywords = $_GET['keywords'];
    $whereQueries[] = "member_group_id LIKE '$keywords'";
}

# Construct "WHERE ..." part of query
$whereSQL = 'WHERE ';
$firstLoop = true;
foreach ($whereQueries as $q) {
    if (!$firstLoop) {  # Avoid prepending "AND" on the first loop
        $firstLoop = false;
        $q = " AND $q";
    }
    $whereSQL .= $q;
}

# Construct "ORDER BY ..." part of query
$orderSQL = 'ORDER BY ';
$firstLoop = true;
foreach ($orderQueries as $q) {
    if (!$firstLoop) {
        $firstLoop = false;
        $q = ", $q";  # Avoid prepending "," on the first loop
    }
    $orderSQL .= " $q"
}
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM ILFREE_core_members $whereSQL  $orderSQL LIMIT $start,$limit");
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /web/htdocs/www.ilfree.it/home/test/getData.php on line 52

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /web/htdocs/www.ilfree.it/home/test/getData.php on line 37

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /web/htdocs/www.ilfree.it/home/test/getData.php on line 47

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in /web/htdocs/www.ilfree.it/home/test/getData.php:61 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /web/htdocs/www.ilfree.it/home/test/getData.php on line 61

Comment: Sorry, there were three errors in my code. Two mistyped variable names and also it was not flagging subsequent loops correctly to add "AND" and "," to the query.  Can you try again please.